# EntityFramework 5 datafirst approach

Tags: entity-framework

I have built a projct using datafist approach initially but now I seem to be having problem when database changes are done and new requirements are given.Every time I have to recreate the edmx updating the edmx sometimes doesn't work.Is there a way where I can go back codefirst approach where I can imitate the datafirst approach say by using power tools?

thanks in advance

Comment: There is no way to update a _code-first_ model from the database like an edmx can be updated.

Comment: @GertArnold: of course there is, the power tools have the "reverse engineer database" which recreates the model from the database.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Yes, but it does not update an existing model as is possible in an edmx.

Comment: But is there any other way where every time a person does changes to db i have generate entities or update the edmx.I was thinking of having many contexts instead of one, so if there db changes on one table then i do'nt have to update the entire edmx or generate entities again and again.

Comment: Try to create new edmx('s). If the issue persists, try to sort it out, maybe by asking a new question specifically on that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I work with the entity classes outside of edmx, I only use edmx to generate the initial class and their mappings. After I have generated the entities, I move the generated code. So, you could copy and paste the code in the cs files into your app_code (if you have one) or a separate class project. You'll also need to change the references in your project to point to your new class or DLL.

I should add that subsequent changes to your model will be "code first" and you will also need to move your context class to get it working. This is not a way to imitate the datafirst approach though, this is strictly code first.

Comment: But is there any other way where every time a person does changes to db i have generate entities or update the edmx.I was thinking of having many contexts instead of one, so if there db changes on one table then i do'nt have to update the entire edmx or generate entities again and again.

Comment: Having many contexts instead of one big context is definitely the way to go. Anything else is very bad practice in most cases. I dont know of any way to do this automatically (if i am understanding you correctly). Every time a database changes, you need to update the entity somehow to reflect the changes.